# Error in OleDB connection string

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

i am using OleDB connection to Accdb file. but it is showing error

**Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.**

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

i dont know why it still shows erro showing **keyword not suppoeted: 'provider'**

My Web Config

> ```
>    <connectionStrings>
>     <add name="PPAPConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\ACCESS2013\TS16949_Linker.accdb" 
>     providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB"/>
>     </connectionStrings>
> ```

Code

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PPAPConnectionString").ConnectionString
 Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
Dim qry As String
qry = "Select * from pfd_op_type where id=" & GridView1.SelectedDataKey.ToString
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)
cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(qry, con)
Dim da As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
typ_code_Num.Text = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString
Op_Typ_Name.Text = dt.Rows(0)(1).ToString
```

End Sub

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5384504
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +113
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `providerName=System.Data.OleDb` and fix the missing semicolon after the database name

Comment: **It is still the same**

Comment: Are you certain that the error comes from the code shown? Could you post also the Stack Trace ?

Comment: Edited Question ( Added Stack Trace ) 
I have not used SQL client anywhere, still i dont know why it is showing Line 3,4,6,7 in Stack Trace

Comment: There is an [SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) control somewhere in your markup without the ProviderName property set to a System.Data.OleDb? The default is System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That was correct.

Comment: Then post your solution here as an answer. You could help a lot a future reader that finds this question by searching for keywords  like `Error`, `OleDB`, `connection string` or the whole error message